# Mathematical Expression Editor Library / Plugins

Tags: android, ios, html, mathml

I gone through few(HostMath.com, MathJax, WIRIK, etc), Looking for libraries (free / paid) which helps the users in writing mathematical expressions on Web, Android, IOS.

Comment: So what is your question.??

Comment: Please suggest any library that we can use universally.'

Answer (score 0):

MathJax library is most useful and supports majority of platforms.